# C manipulate directories : how to position at a directory by giving its name in main arguments

Tags: c, directory, argv, opendir

I'm having trouble to manipulate directories in C.

1. I want to give the name of 2 directories as argument on main
2. check if the first directory exists (in the current path)
3. open the directory
4. call a function (that i created) to create files and do stuff inside
   the directory
5. close the directory and go into the 2nd directory and do the same .

I wrote my code but it still not doing the stuffs inside the directories that i gave on main, instead it looks like i'm always positioned in the current directory, so is the call to open the directory not good???

Here's what I've done :

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       int i = 0;
       char cwd[1024];
       if(argc < 3)
       {
            printf("Erreur dans les arguments\n");
       } else 
       {
          for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
          {
            if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL)
            {
                printf("an error occured when getting current directory\n");
            }
            // make a path to the directory
            strcat(cwd, "/");
            strcat(cwd, argv[i]);
            strcat(cwd, "/");
            printf("cwd %s\n", cwd);
            //check if directory exist and readable
            //if((rep = opendir(argv[i])) != NULL) not working also
            if((rep = opendir(cwd)) != NULL)
            {
               getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
               printf("cwd %s\n", cwd);

              // do some stuff on the directory 

              //int result = createFile("file.txt"); // this function works fine but the file is always created in the current directory
            }
        }
     }
   }
```

if anyone could help, it will be appreciated. Thank u.

Comment: @chux No declaration is visible in this code .

Comment: @chux and ameyCU sorry guys, this is a part of a big program that i made and i didn't want to put all the program here, that's why i forget the boucle for, i'm really sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: You only need to call `getcwd()` once, unless you use `chdir()` to change directory.  You don't need to prefix the value from `getcwd()`; you can use `.` to mean the current directory.  Or you can simply use the name unchanged; the user can type an absolute name (starting with `/`) or a relative name (not starting with `/`) as they choose.  That gives the best flexiibility.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler all i want is to enter in the directory i specify in argv ( which it must exists in the current directory) and do my stuff there,  than close it and do the same for the next argv... but i'm not able,, i'm trying but no results >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    char path[1024];

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s dir1 dir2 [...]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        DIR *rep;
        if ((rep = opendir(argv[i])) != NULL)
        {
            struct dirent *dp;
            while ((dp = readdir(rep)) != 0)
            {
                if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0)
                    continue;
                printf("Name: %s/%s\n", argv[i], dp->d_name);
            }
            closedir(rep);

            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", argv[i], "filename.txt");
            FILE *fp = fopen(path, "w");

            if (fp == 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create file %s\n", path);
            else
            {
                fprintf(fp, "File %s created successfully\n", path);
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ mkdir junk1 junk1/subdir junk2 junk2/subdir-too
$ cp /dev/null junk1/forget-me-not
$ cp /dev/null junk2/hallelujah-chorus
$ ./dodir junk1 junk2
Name: junk1/forget-me-not
Name: junk1/subdir
Name: junk2/hallelujah-chorus
Name: junk2/subdir-too
$ ls -l junk?
junk1:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  45 Oct 25 00:11 filename.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   0 Oct 25 00:11 forget-me-not
drwxr-xr-x  2 jleffler  staff  68 Oct 25 00:11 subdir

junk2:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  45 Oct 25 00:11 filename.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   0 Oct 25 00:11 hallelujah-chorus
drwxr-xr-x  2 jleffler  staff  68 Oct 25 00:11 subdir-too
$ rm -fr junk?
$
```

Comment: so of i resume : opendir(argv[i]) to open directory with the name given, readdir(rep) to read what's in the directory and u can get a path to that directory than created file ..etc. now is there a way to call this function (i'll list bellow) that takes any string as parameter and execute it inside a directory argv[i] , i dont know how to give it a path or to be positioned in argv[i] withowt using a path :          int createFolder(char *target)  
{
    char buffer[100] = {0};
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "mkdir %s", target);
    return(system(buffer));
}

Comment: how u indent the code in comment?? because mine it looks horrible ...>.<"

Comment: I showed how to create a file in the directory; you can do it in a function instead of in the main program.  Using `system()` and the `mkdir` command is clumsy; use the `mkdir()` system call instead.  You have to pass at least `argv[i]` and possibly the sub-directory name to your `createFolder()` function, that's all.

Comment: You enclose code in back-ticks ``(`…`)`` to get it to look like code.  It's harder to get back-ticks to appear in the comment, though.  For that, I used ```(``(`…`)``)``` (the parentheses may help get the back-ticks to appear).  And … no; the recursion can stop there.  It is really gruesome trying to document Markdown in Markdown.

Comment: omg i could pass the entire path to my function !! right, i need to modify my function createfolder() ..omg that is the clue i think , i hope it will works , i'm not sleeping today xD

Comment: the code works now like I want, i just needed to pass the path for the function like u said, thank u so much u really helped me  lot, and u took the time to explain everything, i appreciated so much.

Answer (score 0):

`opendir` doesn't change the current working directory. It opens
up a directory and gives you a handle to it.

You need to call `chdir` to actually change the current working directory.

Comment: thank u for answering me, so if i do int cpt = chdir(cwd); automatically i'll positioned at the directory and then i call the function to create the file ?

Comment: @Potato: You can use `chdir()`, but you need to be careful if you do.  Processing the second directory name is going to be more difficult if you do (look up `fchdir()` and how to open a directory so you can use `fchdir()`).  You can probably do your work without `chdir()`; simply prefix the directory name you were given to any name you need to work with.  Note that the names from `readdir()` will only contain the name relative to the directory you're reading from; you need to prefix the name with the directory name unless you do the `chdir()`, but I'd avoid the `chdir()` if possible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thank u for the answers :), but i still can't fix it, i'm not sure if u understand what i want to do. please tell me : is  if((rep = opendir(argv[i])) != NULL)  means i'm positionned in the directory argv[i]? if the directory is opened why i can't do my stuff in there?

Comment: @Potato: There's a massive difference between `opendir(argv[i])` and `chdir(argv[i])`. The first lets you read the names of the files from the directory, whether it's the process's current directory or not. The second changes the meaning of relative names such as `./subdir/filename` or `filename` — but not of absolute names such as `/path/to/subdir/filename`. You can do stuff in the directory whether your process has it as the current directory or not. However, the way you reference the files depends on whether you've done the `chdir()` or not. The problem with the `chdir()` is getting back.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler from what u're saying i think i don't need to use chdir() to fix my problem, i don't really need to change the path. but i though when we want to do something in a directory we just have to make sure that exists right? like this :  if((rep = opendir(argv[i])) != NULL) { createfile()}, and then the file will be created in argv[i], i passed 3 hours and i can't figure it, this supposed to be easy but yet nothing.

Comment: @Potato: Correct; it is not mandatory to use `chdir()` — unless there are instructions for your homework that you've not let us know about — and I suggest that using `chdir()` will cause more problems than not using it.  When you create a file in the directory, you'll create a name from `argv[i]` and whatever you want to specify as the name in the directory, maybe using `snprintf()`:  `namelen = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s/%s", argv[i], filename);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i created directory named "folder" in current directory, i need to pass this name on argv, than check if it exists and than open it and do stuff on it (like create files..etc), can u tell me what,s wrong in the code i wrote? (the only problem there is that i'm creating files outside the directory "folder")i dont want to use chdir()  really :p , and thank u again for all this explanation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok actually i'm working with processes, fork(), pipe, and everything so i can't put all the program here XD , but the only problem i've at this moment is opening the directory and call functions to create files, create directory, delete file on it.

Comment: @Potato: You're close; see my answer.  You're right we don't want to see a huge listing of all your source code — your code is only a little too minimal for it to be a good MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  What I've written is a moderate approximation to an MCVE.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i'm analyzing ur code  than i'll execute it. but did u wrote it on C++? , i'm talking about this : strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") , from where did u get d_name?  and why need to use  struct dirent *dp;? , i'm really sorry for asking too much questions, i'm not an expert on C language :P :P, and thank u thank u

Comment: No; it uses C99 or C11, not C89/90.  I don't code to the quarter-century old standard any more; I assume that compilers support at least the standard from 16 years ago, and normally the one from 5 years ago.  `struct dirent` is the other half of `DIR *`; you get a `DIR *` from `opendir()` and you can then read the entries from the opened directory with `readdir()`, and `readdir()` returns a `struct dirent *` (hence `dp`).  _It might also be sensible to comment on my code under my answer, not under Mark's answer._

Comment: @Potato - to answer your question, yes, you could use my suggestion to `chdir` and a file created will be placed there, but @JonathanLeffler has a better solution.  My question was simply answering why your code wasn't changing directories.