# Create Directory and Store File (C programming)

Tags: c, directory

I want to create a directory that has the name ends with the process ID (to make it unique) and then store the new files that I just wrote inside that directory.

**What I want:**

1) Create a new directory named : *mydirectory.1923* (example of the process id number)

2) Store a file that I just created using

```
FILE * fPointer = fopen("new.txt",w+)
```

into  *mydirectory.1923*

**What I have so far is this:**

```
int bufSize = 20;
int pid = getpid();
char *fileName = malloc(bufSize);
char *prefix = "that.rooms.";
snprintf(fileName, bufSize,"%s%d", prefix, pid);
printf("%s\n",fileName);
struct stat st = {0};
if (stat(fileName, &st) == -1) {
    mkdir(fileName, 0755);
}
DIR *dir = opendir (fileName);
if (dir != NULL) {

    FILE *fLib = fopen("library.txt" , "w+");
    fclose(fLib);

}
closedir(fileName);

return 0;
```

**My Question:**

This code doesn't work, apparently it says error on  the DIR part.

Is this the right thing to do if I want to create directory, create file and store that file directly to the new directory?

Is there any suggestion or advice to do it better than this? Thank you.

Comment: Remarkably similar to [C — manipulate directories …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326565/).  You'd do well to allocate more space for your directory name (you only allow for a 4-digit PID, not a 5-digit PID).  You should rename `fileName` as `dirName` really; it is a more accurate name, at least.  You don't need `opendir()`.  You need to append `library.txt` to the name in `dirName` (so you need still more space).  Note that the `opendir()` could fail if there is already a file with the same name as the directory name you avoided trying to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments:

- As commented above, you should really allocate more space for your dir's name, a 5 digit pid will break your code right away. There are the macros `PATH_MAX` and `FILE_MAX` in `limits.h`
- You don't need to open the directory for anything. This is usually used to iterate over items in directories. You only want to create a file in it.
- Even if you don't really need it, the `closedir` function receives a `DIR *` argument, which I suppose would be `dir` in your code.
- To create the file inside the new directory you should include your dir in the path on creation, or at least `chdir` to it before the `fopen` call. I don't recommend the latter as it affects the process wide working directory.

Below is a quick and dirty patched version of your code that creates the directory and the new file inside it taking into account the above:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int pid = getpid();
    char dirName[NAME_MAX+1];
    char *prefix = "that.rooms.";
    snprintf(dirName, NAME_MAX + 1,"%s%d", prefix, pid);
    printf("%s\n",dirName);
    struct stat st = {0};
    if (stat(dirName, &st) == -1) {
        if(mkdir(dirName, 0755) != -1){
            char libPath[PATH_MAX+1];
            snprintf(libPath, PATH_MAX + 1, "%s/library.txt", dirName);

            FILE *fLib = fopen(libPath , "w+");
            fclose(fLib);
        }else{
            perror("mkdir: ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Changed the variable names a bit so it's clearer:

- `dirName` is used to hold the directory name. It uses `NAME_MAX` as this is the system limit for the length of a file name
- `libPath` is used to hold the path to the `library.txt` file you are creating. If your pid was 3123, `libPath` would read `that.rooms.3123/library.txt` after the `snprintf` call. It uses `PATH_MAX` as this is the system limit for a the length of a file's path.

Comment: I completely forgot about the space thing. Thank you for reminding me and also the correct version of my code. Btw, may I know what is the used for `char libname[PATH_MAX+1]` for again?

Comment: I edited the answer so it's clearer. `libPath` is used to hold the relative path to the `library.txt` file you are creating.

Comment: Also, please consider accepting the answer if you find it does indeed answer your question!